# Не работает Debug

Tags: python, django

В файле settings.py на сервере Ubuntu, Debug = False, но все ошибки все равно детально отображаються в браузере. Проверил значение через shell там оно тоже False. Может кто-нибудь подсказать что делать?

Comment: Регистр точно правильный в settings.py? Должно быть именно `DEBUG = True` или `DEBUG = False`
Нигде больше в коде настройки не импортируются/меняются?

Comment: Да у меня написано DEBUG = False, ну я нигде не импортировал настройки и значение DEBUG тоже не меняю(

Comment: А настройки LOGGING не менялись? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Comment: Нет, я их вообще не трогал

Comment: А сервер пробовали перезапускать?

Comment: да , делал команду sudo service nginx restart

Comment: @yaschk а `sudo systemctl restart nginx`? (раз на убунту работаете)

Comment: @super16 только что попробовал ничего не поменялось

Comment: а что в `pip freeze`? Есть вероятность что какая-то библиотека делает дебаг

Comment: @super16 Django==2.2.1
django-modeltranslation==0.13.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
Pillow==6.0.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0

Comment: @yaschk gunicorn тоже надо перезапустить

Comment: @super16 все заработало спасибо тебе большое!!